# I have a CSS and I want all the items to be aligned in-line

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a ReactJS code and I want a desired result but its not coming up. I'm using material UI tab and I want this in line with the icon. I want the tabs and `Arrowbackicon` to be aligned in line as it is shown in the image:

Here is what I want:

[image]

---

Here is what I have so far:
[image]

---

Here is the CSS part:

```
.MuiTabs-root {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.tab__section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.tab__section>.MuiSvgIcon-root {
    margin-top: 12px;
}

.MuiTabs-flexContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center
}
```

Here is the ReactJS part:

```
const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(0);

const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setSelectedTab(newValue);
}

<div className="tab__section">
    <ArrowBackIcon />

    <Tabs 
        value={selectedTab} 
        onChange={handleChange}
        TabIndicatorProps={
            {
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: "blue",
                    height: "4px",
            }
        }}
    >
        <Tab label="Synchronize Cabinet"></Tab>
        <Tab label="Schedule Information"></Tab>
    </Tabs>

    {selectedTab === 0 && <SyncCabinet />}
    {selectedTab === 1 && <ScheduleInfo />}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cancel margin-top for icon and add `align-items: center` for tab__section

```
.tab__section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `tab__section` class is incorrect for the desired UI. You should also remove the `margin-top` from the icon. It should be as below:

```
.tab__section {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between
}
```